# Is there a tool that allows me to code for email template and see its Outlook layout real time?

Tags: outlook, html-email

I am trying to make an email layout cross compatible with all clients, but is getting slowed down because I have to use Outlook everytime I make changes. Actually it seems like the only method is to use litmus, so what happens is whenever I make changes to my code, I send a test email to my litmus, then only from there I can check the cross compatibility.

Is there a software/tool I can use to see the layout real time as how I code?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this question is off-topic for SO. I don't participate on softwarereqs.se, but you _may_ have better luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you have Litmus, use [Litmus Builder](https://litmus.com/email-builder)!** You can code in one half of the screen and get updated previews of any client in the right every time you save. Worth the $$$ if you work on email regularly.

---

Another way is to use Microsoft Outlook. **Microsoft Outlook uses a similar (if not same) rendering engine as Microsoft Word.**

If you have a compiled HTML file of the email and have Microsoft Word installed on your computer, you can right-click the HTML file and **Open With -> Microsoft Word** to open the email file in Word. What you see should be *very* similar to Outlook.